# How to deserialize json with html using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I'm having below json

```
{"data":"<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>"}
```

Trying to deserialize this `Map<String,String>`

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

objectMapper.readValue("{"data":"<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>"}", Map.class );
```

above code giving the exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('1' (code 49)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (String)"{"data":"<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>"}"; line: 1, column: 30]
```

I will get many number of keys like `data`. That's the reason trying to deserialize it as Map<String, String>.

Want to deserialize, key as `data` and value as `<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>`

Is there any way to deserialize it as Map<String, String> using jackson?

Note: Jackson version using `2.13.x`

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. The inner `"` should be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, your JSON is invalid. You need to escape the quotes inside the JSON string:

```json
{"data":"<p><br data-mce-bogus=\"1\"></p>"}
```

Additionally if you use that JSON inside a Java string literal you have to escape the quotes and the backslashes again:

```java
objectMapper.readValue("{\"data\":\"<p><br data-mce-bogus=\\\"1\\\"></p>\"}", Map.class );
```

Comment: Is there any way to add escape automatically/programatically?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Invald JOSN is invalid. What is the source of the broken JSON? Why is it broken?

Comment: <br data-mce-bogus="1"> this is automatically added by tinyMCE

Comment: What does tinyMCE have to do with this? Why would it manipulate JSON? You really need to show the much bigger picture. It no use just adding small pieces in new information after each question.